# I want a custom task pane in outlook below the mailing list

Tags: outlook, ms-office, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to insert a custom task pane below the mails (of inbox or other folder) in outlook. It should look something like this.

[I want to add the green area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkU3e.jpg)

This is possible with a third party tool add-in express. But i want to do this without any third party tools. How do I do this? The custom task pane in outlook doesn't the flexibility to do this, but how is this possible with the third party tool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use low level Windows API to parent your custom control to the right Outlook HWND. Using Addn-in Express is a much easier alternative.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook/ and https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/